# Apache server cannot allocate memory for new process

Tags: apache, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, child-process

I have a apache server with 32 GB of RAM. When I start the server and execute top to see the resources It show me that the CPU is at 95 percent. It doesn't a normal behaviour and after a few minutes it raises:

> apache cannot allocate memory fork unable to fork new process

I don't know how to solve the problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem to fix it there is 2 options:

1- move from micro instances to small and this was the change that solved the problem (micro instances on amazon tend to have large cpu steal time)

2- tune the mysql database server configuration and my apache configuration to use a lot less memory.

tuning guide for a low memory situation such as this one: http://www.narga.net/optimizing-apachephpmysql-low-memory-server/ (But don't use the suggestion of MyISAM tables - horrible...)

this 2 options will make the problem much much less happening .. I am still looking for better solution to close the process that are done and kill the ones that hang in there .